# SQL Joining tables and displaying lookup table data for report

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, reference, lookup-tables

Have a view and two other tables that I am trying to pull data from.  To create a report on light colors. Have a  table with ColorID and ColorName what I’m trying to do, is display the ColorName from dbo.LightColor into the columns LightColor0ID, LightColor1ID, etc…

Right now the select statement pulls data from two tables with 1,2,3,4,5,6,etc…  table LightColor references 1 = white, 2 = Blue, 3 = Pink, etc… just need the actual colors names rather than the numerical value.

Here is a sample:

```
SELECT       
  VCT.CallInfoID
  ,DLB.LightBehaviorID
  ,VCT.Name
  ,VCT.Abbreviation
  ,VCT.Description
  ,DLB.LightColor0ID
  ,DLB.LightColor1ID 
  ,DLB.LightColor2ID
  ,DLB.LightColor3ID 
  ,DLB.LightColor4ID 
  ,DLB.LightColor5ID 
  ,DLB.LightColor6ID 
  ,DLB.LightColor7ID 
FROM V_CallInfo VCT JOIN
     LightBehavior DLB
     ON VCT.LightBehaviorID = DLB.LightBehaviorID
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need to `join` to the `LightColor` table multiple times, one for each `name` you want to display:

```
SELECT       
   VCT.CallInfoID
   ,DLB.LightBehaviorID
   ,VCT.Name
   ,VCT.Abbreviation
   ,VCT.Description
   ,LC0.ColorName as Color0
   ,LC1.ColorName as Color1 
   ,LC2.ColorName as Color2
   ,LC3.ColorName as Color3
   ,LC4.ColorName as Color4
   ,LC5.ColorName as Color5
   ,LC6.ColorName as Color6
   ,LC7.ColorName as Color7
FROM V_CallInfo VCT 
   JOIN LightBehavior DLB ON VCT.LightBehaviorID = DLB.LightBehaviorID
   JOIN LightColor LC0 ON DLB.LightColor0ID = LC0.ColorID
   JOIN LightColor LC1 ON DLB.LightColor1ID = LC1.ColorID
   ...
   JOIN LightColor LC7 ON DLB.LightColor7ID = LC7.ColorID
```

---

Forgot to mention, if there are any lights with `null` values, then you may need to use `outer joins` instead:

`LEFT JOIN LightColor...`